# Light Projection mapping on Cycles

Tags: shaders, lighting, shader-nodes, vector-mapping

I'm making a 3d projection mapping on a building but first wanted to visualize how would the projection look like on blender and decided to give it a try with spot light projecting my animation on to the building surface what im wondering is there way to map the distortion to fit it to the camera angle/building as in real life video mapping situation( such as using software like resulome arena or madmapper any help would be appreciated. and yes I ve considered making the building surface as emissive with the video as well but that's not what i want I want to be able to simulate the projection.[image]
I mean yes i could move the spot light meticulously left and right to get the distortion just right but there must be a way to control it within node setup.